# Why does a hashtable degenerate into a Linked List when a hashcode() implementation returns a constant value?

Tags: java, algorithm, equals, hashcode

```
// The worst possible legal hash function - never use!
@Override public int hashCode() { return 42; }
```

> It’s legal because it ensures that equal objects have the same hash code. It’s atrocious because it ensures that every object has the same hash code. Therefore, every object hashes to the same bucket, and hash tables degenerate to linked lists. Programs that should run in linear time instead run in quadratic time.

Am trying to figure the above out (quote from pg 47, Item 9, Joshua Bloch's Effective Java).

The way I see it is as follows (consider the following code):

```
Map<String, String> h = new HashMap<String,String>();
h.put("key1", "value1");
h.put("key1", "value2");
```

What happens with the second `h.put("key1",...)` command is as follows:
1. Get the hashcode of `key1`
2. Get to the bucket representing the above hashcode
3. Within that bucket, for each object, invoke the equals method to find whether an identical object exists.

This is kind of faster, because first you find the 'group' (bucket) of objects and then the actual object.

Now, when the hashcode implementation is such that it returns the same integer (such as `42` above) for *ALL* objects, then there is only one bucket, and the equals method needs to be invoked one-by-one on each object in the entire hashmap/hashtable. This is as bad as a linked list because if the objects where in a linked list, then too, one would have to go through them one by one comparing (calling equals) each object.

Is that why, it was said, that the hashtables *degenerate* into a linked list ?

(I apologize for the verbosity of the above text. I am not clear enough in my concepts to have stated it more succinctly)

Comment: *"I apologize for the verbosity of the above text."*  Stuff that, thanks for an interesting question.

Comment: It is a slightly misleading generalization to say that hash tables degenerate. A more correct statement would be that the implementation degenerates into a bucket search, which in this case happens to be implemented as a linked list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HashTable is an array with mapping function (hashCode). When inserting into the array you calculate the position and insert the element there.

BUT, the hashCode does not guarantee, that every element will have a different position, so some objects might collide (have the same address) and the hashTable has to resolve it. There are two common approaches, how to do that.

**Separate chaining**

In separate chaining (used in Java) every index of the array contains a linked list - so every bucket (position) has a infinite capacity. Hence if your hashCode returns only one value, you are using only one liked list => hashTable is a linked list.

**Linear probing**

Second approach is a linear probing. In linear probing the inner array is really normal array of elements. When you find out, that the position is already occupied, you iterate over the array and place the new element at the first empty position.

So I your impl of hashCode generates contant value for every element, you are generating only colisions, hence you are trying to place all the elements to the same index and because is always occupied, you iterate over all aready placed elements and place the new element at the end of `this structure`. If you read again, what you are doing, you must see, that you are using only a different (you can say implicit) implementation of a linked list.

**Why not to do it**

You really should not return constant values, because hashtables are built to provide `O(1)` expected complexity of search and insert operations (because of the hash function, which returns a different address for (almost) every different object). If you return only one value, the implementation degrades to linked list with `O(n)` for both operations.

Comment: IIRC, the Sun implementations of both `Hashtable` and `HashMap` use separate chaining, not linear probing.

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time out to answer so thoroughly. Your explanation answered my question perfectly. THANKS !!

Comment: It may be worthwhile to note that linear probing is just a particular case of a more generalized probing approach; for "add-only" collections, generalized probing approaches may achieve performance comparable to separate chaining, but with less storage overhead (linear probing often has much worse performance except when hash tables are largely empty).  The big problem with probing approaches is that item removal is difficult.  It's slightly easier with linear probing than other approaches, but in general separate chaining is better *if a collection will need to support item removal*.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your understanding seems accurate.  However, it is not *like* a linked list.  The actual internal implementation of entries that share a common bucket *is* a plain old linked list.  The bucket holds the Map.Entry at the head of the list and each entry has a forward pointer to the next occupant of its bucket.  (For the implementation of HashMap that's built into Java of course.)

Answer (score 3):

Hash tables -- when used correctly -- offer constant-time lookups on average. In terms of time complexity, constant time is as good as it gets.

Linked lists offer linear-time lookups. Linear time (i.e. look at every element in turn) is as bad as it gets.

When a hash table is misused in the manner described by Bloch, its lookup behaviour *degenerates* into that of a linked list, simply because it effectively *becomes* a linked list.

Similar things can be said about other operations.